# Problems with NSTimeInterval timeIntervalSinceDate

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I want to code an alarm clock for iOS.

My code for calculating the difference between current time and alarm time:

```
NSDate *date = picker.date;
                    NSLog(@"[date description] %@",[date description]);
                    NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                    [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"]; //24h time format
                    NSString *dateString = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:picker.date];
                    NSLog(@"[date description] %@",dateString);

                    NSDate *startDate = [outputFormatter dateFromString:dateString];



                    NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
                    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
                    NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
                    NSDate *endDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:resultString];
                    NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate]; 


                    double minutes = timeDifference / 60;
                    double hours = minutes / 60;
                    double seconds = timeDifference;
```

...which leads to these variables:

```
startDate = 2000-01-01 06:45:26 +0000
endDate = 2000-01-01 22:46:36 +0000
seconds = 57670 (= 16.01944 hours).
```

How to get to calculate the real time difference of 28740 seconds?

Comment: What is 28740 seconds?

Comment: Agreed, why do you think the difference is not 16 hrs (57670 seconds)?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass timeDifference in below method. It will give you Hours,Minutes and Seconds.

```
- (NSString *)timeFormatted:(int)totalSeconds{
int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
int hours = totalSeconds / 3600;
return hours==0 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d",hours, minutes, seconds];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

**Get time difference in hour, minutes,seconds from `NSTimeInterval`:**

```
//.......
    NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
        long ti = lroundf(timeInterval);

    int hour = ti / 3600;
    int mins = (ti % 3600) / 60;
    int secs = ti % 60;
```

***OR***

**Get time difference in hour, minutes,seconds from Dates:**

```
// Get the system calendar
NSCalendar *objCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

// Create the NSDates
NSDate *currentTime = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDate *startDate = picker.date;

// Get conversion to months, days, hours, minutes
unsigned int unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *TimeInfo = [objCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate: currentTime  toDate:startDate  options:0];

NSLog(@" %dmin %dhours %ddays %dmoths ",[TimeInfo minute], [TimeInfo hour], [TimeInfo day], [TimeInfo month]);
```